# How to mimic SQL joinings with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I join two objects (scores & persons) into one single object (joined). I am kind struggling with this as I am noobie with JavaScript and I am using Meteor+Mongo combo.

```
var scores = [
{person_id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9}
];

var persons = [
{person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12},
{person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15},
{person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10}
];


var joined = [
{person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", score_math: 0, score_biology: 0, score_chemistry: 0}];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposal with a temporary object and some array methods in vanilla JS.

```js
var scores = [{ person_id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9 }, { person_id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9 }],
    persons = [{ person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12 }, { person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15 }, { person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10 }],
    joined = persons.map(function (a) {
        function setProp(o) { Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) { object[k] = o[k]; }); }
        var object = {};
        setProp(a);
        setProp(this[a.person_id] || { score_math: 0, score_biology: 0, score_chemistry: 0 });
        return object;
    }, scores.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.person_id] = a;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(joined, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];
_.forEach(scores,function(score){
    var person = _.find(persons,{person_id:score.person_id});
    result.push(_.extend({}, score, person));
});
```

This is a simplified version. I don't handle value not found and so on. `forEach`will loop on all score. Then I `find` the first matching person supposing it's unique. Then i merge them using `extend` into a new object.

Be carefull with this kind of thing, if you have a huge amount of datasets, those kinds of task have to be handled by the back. If you really need to perform lot of joins and can change the DBMS, you may go for a RDBMS if it fits more.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```js
var scores = [
{person_id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9}
];

var persons = [
{person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12},
{person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15},
{person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10}
];
var joined = [];
for (var i=0; i<persons.length; i++) {
  var new_object = {};
  var found = false;
  for (var j=0; j<scores.length; j++) {
    if (scores[j].person_id == persons[i].person_id) {
      found = true;
      // copy all the values from score
      for (var key in scores[j]) {
        new_object[key] = scores[j][key];
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    for (var key in scores[0]) {
      new_object[key] = 0;
    }
  }
  for (var key in persons[i]) {
    new_object[key] = persons[i][key];
  }
  joined.push(new_object);
}
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(joined, true, 2) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a flat merged object, I suggest you to create a new object that contains both persons and scores details.

You can leverage on [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and on [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions to manage that.

```
var scores = [
{person_id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9}
];

var persons = [
{person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12},
{person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15},
{person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10}
];

//Function used in the .filter method. 'this' object is actually the person_id
function getScoreByPersonId(score){
  return score.person_id == this;
}

//Basic students implementations. You can enrich the structure of the 'item' object depending on your requirements.
var students = persons.map(function(p){
  var item = {};
  item['person'] = p;
  item['score'] = scores.filter(getScoreByPersonId, p.person_id)[0] || {};
  return item;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by basic array and object operations. Below code is optimized to do it.

```js
var scores = [
{person_id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
{person_id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9}
];

var persons = [
{person_id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12},
{person_id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15},
{person_id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10}
];

innerjoin=function(data1,data2,column){
  var joined=[];
  
  var d1len=data1.length;
  var d2len=data2.length;
  
  // Create dictionary from first array 
  var dict={};
  for(var i=0; i<d1len; i++){
    var item=data1[i];
    var key=item[column];
    var arr=dict[key];
    if(!arr){
      arr=dict[key]=[];
    }
    arr.push(item);
  }
  
  // Join two arrays
  for(var i=0; i<d2len; i++){
    var item=data2[i];
    var key=item[column];
    
    var arr=dict[key];
    if(!arr) continue;
    for(var j=0,lenj=arr.length; j<lenj; j++)
    {
       joined.push(merge(item,arr[j]));
    }
  }
  
  return joined;
}


merge=function(obj1,obj2){
  var res={};
  
  for(var key in obj1){
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) res[key]=obj1[key];
  }
  for(var key in obj2){
    if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) res[key]=obj2[key];
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log(innerjoin(persons,scores,"person_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of joins easily with [StrelkiJS](https://github.com/amaksr/Strelki.js):

```
var persons = new StrelkiJS.IndexedArray();
persons.loadArray([
  {id: "1", person_name: "Bob", home_country: "Wakerly", age: 12},
  {id: "2", person_name: "Arnie", home_country: "Templeton", age: 15},
  {id: "3", person_name: "Steve", home_country: "Elberon", age: 10}
]);

var scores = new StrelkiJS.IndexedArray();
scores.loadArray([
  {id: "1", score_math: 9, score_biology: 9, score_chemistry: 9},
  {id: "2", score_math: 9, score_biology: 8, score_chemistry: 9}
]);

var res = persons.query([{
    from_col:"id",
    to_table: scores,
    to_col: "id",
    type: "outer"
}]);
```

The result will be:

```
[
  [
    {"id":"1","person_name":"Bob","home_country":"Wakerly","age":12},
    {"id":"1","score_math":9,"score_biology":9,"score_chemistry":9}
  ],
  [
    {"id":"2","person_name":"Arnie","home_country":"Templeton","age":15},
    {"id":"2","score_math":9,"score_biology":8,"score_chemistry":9}
  ],
  [
    {"id":"3","person_name":"Steve","home_country":"Elberon","age":10},
    null
  ]
]
```